# Access webpage from terminal

Tags: ssh, browser, remote-access

I have router web admin access via WAN disabled. I can however access a LAN server terminal via SSH. Can I access the router's web admin page triggered from the server terminal, i.e. as if I was entering a private IP address in a web browser on the LAN? If so, how is this done?

Answer (score 0):

[lynx](http://lynx.isc.org) (text web browser). I believe it available on all Linux distro.

Comment: The admin page requires Javascript to be enabled, which Lynx does not support so unfortunately it does not work in this specific case.